# Clustering vs unsupervised classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have heard of the difference between "classification" and "clustering". "Classification" is supervised and "clustering" is unsupervised. But, there is also a term "unsupervised classification", so is "unsupervised classification" the same thing as "clustering"?

Comment: "unsupervised classification" is used by people who work on supervised classification, that don't want to admit that clustering is something rather different. This way, it sounds like a lower quality version of classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clustering** is an **unsupervised classification** as there is no prior knowledge is assumed to be available.

See if below provided link could be helpful:
http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/classification/node12.html